# Logs not printing in file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to print logs using logger module in python.
Following is the code I am keeping on the top of file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOG_FILENAME = '/home/akash/exdion-pdf-extracter/doc/epod.log'
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=LOG_FILENAME,
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        )
```

There are different files with function calls from one another. I have used the following line to display a line in the logger.

```
@staticmethod
def initiate_pdf_processing(ct_doc, pt_doc, feature, startAndEndKeyList):
    logging.info("testing logger")
    ...
```

There are multiple instances of the similar above logger function. But I can't receive the logger output in the designated file. The code and files are huge. However there are a few error generated by the code which are getting printed in the log file.

Comment: I never used that module in python, but a quick read trough the documentation suggests that maybe you have to get a logger after doing the configuration, as in `logger = logging.getLogger('tcpserver')`. This method gets a `Logger` object which has the `info()`, `error()`, etc...methods. You seem to be calling the `info()` method of the module itself instead of the Logger object and i'm surprised that even runs.

Comment: That runs. It's printing log.error() but not log.info()

Comment: Does the python community of stackoverflow follows - DOWNVOTE -> READ -> REVIEW. It's better to mention the error and wait for sometime to resolve rather downvoting. Do they expect me to find the answer myself then put the question here? Hell irritated with these python community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code bit out of the `main` namespace. This way, you are defining a logger and creating a log file as global file, and you can call the logger anywhere in  the code. A logger code bit below is how I usually code.

```
logfile = '<your_file_name>.log'
if(os.path.isfile(logfile)):
        os.remove(logfile)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(pathname)s [%(process)d]: %(levelname)s:: %(message)s'))

logger = logging.getLogger('wbs-server-log')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Comment: The log messages are also printed in terminal

Comment: Glad that that worked and thanks for `logger.propagate = False`

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you have to initialize logging above `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. That way logging will be initialized when you import this as module.

Suggestion for initializing logging:

```
import logging 

log = logging.getLogger(PACKAGE_NAME)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=open(LOG_FILE_NAME, 'a'))
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(stream_handler)

log.debug('your message here')
```

After this you can tweak log message formatting with `logging.Formatter`.